# is there any way to find reason for .net app crash even if Exceptions are caught

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception, crash

I have .net App that pings a particular port after login.I have surrounded the logic in try catch and have caught a System.net.webException in my logs. But in some windows machines this causes an app crash in random.

```
Error Message: WebException

Exception Type: System.Net.WebException

Error Location : Unable to connect to the remote server

InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 127.0.0.1:9000
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

StackTrace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at tpsyncagent.MainWindow.<ConnectToTally>d__36.MoveNext() in C:\code\tpdesktopsyncagent\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 247
```

This is the code Snippet

```cs
try
{
    Stream dataStream = TallyRequest.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //logging code
}
```

Comment: You can check the windows event viewer for the exception

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting random crashes then try placing a catch-all exception handler in your App class:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    ... etc ...
```

Then in that handler dump the exception's message, inner exception and StackTrace to see where it's being thrown. In this particular case you know it's a SocketException, so you can also cast the exception to that and check its SocketErrorCode property for more info.